# Flutter In app Purchase ExamplePaymentQueueDelegate not calling

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

Flutter Doctor -v

[image]

I am trying to run the in app purchase sample but ExamplePaymentQueueDelegate is not calling.

```
class ExamplePaymentQueueDelegate implements SKPaymentQueueDelegateWrapper {
  @override
  bool shouldContinueTransaction(
      SKPaymentTransactionWrapper transaction, SKStorefrontWrapper storefront) {
    debugPrint('Test--->${transaction}'); **--- Not calling this line** 
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldShowPriceConsent() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Source : https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase

I need to get the Original Transaction id when I subscribe the product. In ios it is not working.

Comment: hi, did you solve this problem?